# Eclipse RCP File Explorer

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Is there a good Eclipse RCP file explorer out there? I need a platform independent file explorer which should be extensible through plugins. I only found [File Arranger](http://sourceforge.net/projects/filearranger/), which seems to be outdated.

I just ask cause I want to develop such an explorer, but it wouldn't make sense if there is already a solution out there.

Answer (score 1):

I did not find any recent File Explorer.

The Navigator view based on the [old ResourceNavigator](https://www.eclipse.org/lists/platform-ui-dev/msg04134.html) ([bug 268083](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=268083)) is now based on the [CNF (Common Navigator Framework)](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Common_Navigator_Framework), which can be adatped for all sort of trees.

Other plugins exist to add explorer-like feature ([pathtools](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pathtools): [image]
<sub>(source: [googlecode.com](http://pathtools.googlecode.com/files/PathToolsToolbar3.png))</sub>
), but none propose directly a file explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I done something like a File Explorer in college.
Protip: use CNF with Apache VFS, and you can extend it to explore a FTP, a Zip or anything you want.

Comment: Any chance to have a look at that project in a GitHub repo?

Comment: Any screenshots? Where it is uploaded?